# A simple yet complex path integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let L be an elipse arc with parametrization $z = 2 \cos(t) + 4i \sin(t)$, $t \in  [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

How would one solve $\int_{L}^{} z^{-1} dz$?

Comment: Which versions of Cauchy's integral formula and integral theorem do you already know?

Comment: Ah, I thought the parameter interval was $[0,2\pi]$, my bad. Fundamental theorem of calculus then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal branch of log is analytic on an open set containing your path so you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to solve the integral.

Comment: Integrating this, you get an inverse trigonometric function with a complex argument. What do you do then?

Comment: Don't use the actual parametrization of the path.  Just use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You only need to evaluate the primitive at the endpoints of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You may deform the integration path into a straight line from $2$ to $4$ quarter circle of radius 4.
The line gives a contribution of
$$\int_2^4 z^{-1} dz=\log 2$$
The quarter circle gives a quarter of $2\pi i$. As the two paths are homotopic, we get
$$ \int_L z^{-1} dz=\log 2+\frac{\pi i}{2} $$